# How to scroll down to latest entry in ng-repeat (AngularJS or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a div with ng-repeat to display posts and an input box to enter new posts. They are sorted such that the latest post is shown at the bottom. Upon adding a new post, I would like to scroll down to see the latest. Is there an angular trick to do this efficiently? Or do I need to use javascript to achieve the desired result?

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | limitTo:-15">
    {{post.uid}} : {{post.text}}
</div>

<form>
  <input type="textarea" class="chatbox" placeholder="Start typing..." ng-model="newPost"/>
  <button class="chatbutton" type="submit" ng-click="addPost(newPost); newPost = null; setInterval();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
</form>
```

Comment: A line or two of JavaScript is not that bad...

Comment: [anchorscroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make this generic by adding a decorating directive.

here is an example that can probably help you to this;

Basically, when a new item is added then the $anchorScroll service will be used to scroll to that specific element.

http://jsbin.com/binoqavopa/18/edit

Comment: Thank you. I tried and it works when the user clicks in a <a> attribute. I tried ng-init and ang-change but both didnt work. How can I include it automatically?

Comment: I have found the solution. Basically my <a> attribute was not within the scope of the scroll controller. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27423012/4262057

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your asking, you can sure use JavaScript for this function. I would suggest depending on your code and what you have happens when a user clicks submit, you can catch the submit process what you need done and then scroll down to the latest post. Not sure how you handle the submit function so it would be hard to show you. But maybe something like this :

Basically you could have all your code for handling the submit and then when the user does click it you scroll to the bottom using something like this:

```
 $("#submit").on("click" ,function(){
            scrolled=scrolled + 2700;
            /* other functions here */
            $(".stuff").animate({
                    scrollTop:  scrolled
               });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution through correct use of anchorScroll (reference by [PSL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009603/psl)). Here is the code:

```
<div id="scrollArea" ng-controller="ScrollController">

  <div style="padding: 10px" ng-repeat="post in posts | limitTo:-10">
    <span class="chatbox" style="background: {{post.pcolor}}">{{post.text}}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="chatname">{{post.pname}} ({{post.time}})</span>
  </div>

<form>
  <input  class="chatinput" placeholder="Start typing..." ng-model="newPost"/>
  <button class="chatbutton" type="submit" ng-click="gotoBottom(); addPost(newPost); newPost = null;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
</form>
<a id="bottom"></a>
</div>
```

Please make sure to but the id="bottom" within the div of the ScrollController:

```
.controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
  function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
      // set the location.hash to the id of
      // the element you wish to scroll to.
      $location.hash('bottom');

      // call $anchorScroll()
      $anchorScroll();
    };
  }])
```

Comment: Try not to add ui logic into your controllers; That's an anti-pattern. This is a perfect use case for a directive; that's one of the reasons they exist

Comment: Similarly, to the one that I wrote. If you tell me what didn't work exactly, I could help you